# Combining two different observableArray into one in knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am trying to combine two different arrays into a generic array then binding it using foreach.

View Model:

```
  self.cancelledItem1 = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.items(), function (item) {
            return (item.category() == 'Cancelled');
        });
    });

   self.cancelledItem2 = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.differntitems(), function (item2) {
            return (item2.status() == 'Cancelled');
        });
    });

    self.allCancelled = ko.observableArray();

    self.combineCancelled = function () {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.cancelledItem1(), function (item) {
                self.allCancelled.push({
                    firstName: item.firstName(),
                    lastName: item.lastName()
                });
            });

            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.cancelledItem2(), function (item2) {
                self.allCancelled.push({
                    firstName: item2.fName(),
                    lastName: item2.lName()
                });
            });
    }
```

cshtml:

```
    $(function () {
           var myViewModel = new MyViewModel(@Html.Raw(Model.ToJson()));
           debugger;
           myViewModel.combineCancelled();
          ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
        }

  <div data-bind="template: {name: 'cancelled-template', foreach: allCancelled }"></div>
  <script type="text/html" id="cancelled-template">
      <div>     
         <div class="header">
            <span data-bind="text:firstName"></span>
            <span data-bind="text:lastName"></span>
         </div>
      <div  class="details">
          .
          .
          .
      </div>
 </script>
```

I can see data and length of "allCancelled" array using debugger and myViewModel.allCancelled()[0].firstName returns value in console but binding is not happening, getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "template: function (){return {name:'cancelled-template',foreach:allCancelled} }"
Message: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return firstName }"
Message: firstName is not defined
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make `allCancelled` a computed observable:

```
self.allCancelled = ko.computed(function () {
    var tempAllCancelled = [];

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.cancelledItem1(), function (item) {
        tempAllCancelled.push({
            firstName: item.firstName(),
            lastName: item.lastName()
        });
    });

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.cancelledItem2(), function (item) {
        tempAllCancelled.push({
            firstName: item.fName(),
            lastName: item.lName()
        });
    });

    return tempAllCancelled;
});
```

Comment: You have it almost good. But there's no need to use an observableArray. I'll edit your answer.

Comment: I challenged myself to make this even more concise, just for fun, interested, see [link](https://jsfiddle.net/bpwLxrxx/11/)

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing a standard JavaScript object, not a Knockout model with observables. There's actually no reason to even go this granular. Just do:

```
self.allCancelled.push(item);
```

Comment: Thanks you for your response. The problem is cancelledItem1 and cancelledItem2 are arrays with totally different properties as I mentioned above, so push(item) doesnt work here.